# json.dumps 'skip over' specific keys?

Tags: python, json, django-templates

Is there a way to have python's json.dumps 'skip over' specific keys, so that certain values are written directly into a  tag?

For example

```
data = {'a_number': 42, 'a_string': 'foo'}
data['a_json_encoded_object'] = '{"foo": "bar"}' #this is a string being read from the DB

dumped = json.dumps(data)
```

Then in an html file, using Django

```
<script>
  var data = {{dumped}}
</script>
```

This results in html of:

```
var data = {"a_json_encoded_object": "{\\"foo\\": \\"bar\\"}", "a_string": "foo", "a_number": 42}
```

But what I want is:

```
var data = {"a_json_encoded_object": {"foo": "bar"}, "a_string": "foo", "a_number": 42}
```

Is there a way to do that?
I.e. to tell json.dumps: for the key 'a_json_encoded_object', don't manipulate the value at all, and write it into the json directly after *"a_json_encoded_object":*

If not, what is best practice for getting a JSON-encoded string from the DB into browser memory? For reference, right now I'm using JSON.parse, but it's messy.

Comment: The `json` module doesn't support any way to tell it "we already serialized this part for you". The closest thing is the `default` method in `json.JSONEncoder`, which has to return an object to be serialized, with no option of performing the serialization itself. There might be 3rd-party modules that support such a thing, but I don't know of any. The best option I know of is to parse the `'{"foo": "bar"}'` part with `json.loads` just so `json.dumps` will reserialize it, which may be wasteful.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping there would be a custom encoder, as you mentioned. Hopefully someone knows of one. As you say, json.loads is wasteful - I might as well stick with the JSON.parse on the client side, since I already have it.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so what you're trying to achieve is the effect of

```
data['a_json_encoded_object'] = {"foo": "bar"}
```

And you have the string

```
'{"foo": "bar"}'
```

From the Database.

Simply use `json.loads` to convert your string back into a Python dictionary

```
>>> json.loads('{"foo": "bar"}')
{u'foo': u'bar'}
```

So

```
data['a_json_encoded_object'] = json.loads('{"foo": "bar"}')
```

Which is the same as

```
data['a_json_encoded_object'] = {"foo": "bar"}
```

In your Django template

```
<script>
     var data = {{ dumped|safe }}  // Mark as safe so quotations won't be escaped
</script>
```

Which renders to

```
var data = {"a_json_encoded_object": {"foo": "bar"}, "a_string": "foo", "a_number": 42}
```

Comment: Thanks. While this works, it is a no less circuitous than the JSON.parse that I'm already doing client side. But it does deliver the right output :)

Comment: It's also an all Python solution.